# Is it possible to use Source Safe over the internet?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

Is it possible to use Source Safe over the internet?

Would you do it?

Comment: I wouldn't use SourceSafe. Period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sourceoffsite](http://www.sourcegear.com/sos/) was specifically made for this - and was a pretty good product if I recall.

I would not use sourcesafe if I had a choice.  Do a search on this site for more details.  It has been beaten to death.

Other popular products are subversion/svn, mercurial and git.  There are of course other commercial products that cost money.  One of them is a sponsor for this site.

EDIT

If you can choose a different tool/product go for one of the others, but you can do it with sourcesafe.

Comment: +1 because that's the answer, but I wouldn't say "don't use it."  Yes, SourceSafe itself is something you'll want to move off of, but if you're stuck you should use SourceoffSite.

Comment: SourceSafe 2005 directly supports HTTP usage in a timezone-safe manner with server components.

Comment: Using SourceSafe beats not using a version control tool at all. I used to work in a shop where some blowhards with authority said "We'll create the process before we choose the tool," and forced us into a cobbled-together folder scheme with *no* versioning of dev files. The developers started using VSS in self defense, 'cause we got it installed with VStudio & couldn't get anything else approved.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a choice, you could use a VPN. But that's going to open all kinds of other security issues. That is, assuming you even have the power to do it.

Comment: +1, and VPN gives you access to other things anyway (internal Wiki?).  Note that this is very slow, but that's mostly SourceSafe's fault.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the version.  IIRC, 2005 supported access via http, and the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_SourceSafe) article seems to corroborate that.

That said, svn+tortoise+ankh will do everything source safe will do and then some, only faster and better, and costs less too.

Answer (score 2):

As developers (and consultants) we cannot always pick the tools that we use. Yes, you can configure VSS to use the HTTP protocol, and while I would not use it over the Internet, I have used it that way, over VPN and LAN connections. It was not always reliable over slow VPN connections (frequent reconnects would occur, but no data loss), and performance was an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Possible?  Yes.  Would I do it? No.  There exists only one condition under which I would use sourcesafe: If it was a job requirement and I had literally no other choice.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that VSS 2005 works ok via a VPN over a high speed connection. There's a way to access it via HTTP. I think it's an install option that sets up a web site for this in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

No I would not. Why not use something more reliable?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it IS possible. My company does.